# Override installed module in import

Tags: python, module

I am currently working on a package that's nearly ready for distribution. As such, I'm trying out installing it (via `setup.py`) on my system. However, I also need access to the current (source code) package, e.g. for tests.

Is it possible to explicitly force importing the local package instead of the installed version? What I already tried is adding the path at the beginning of `sys.paths`, with no luck.

I guess this question goes into how exactly Python looks for the modules to import, and how to change the order.

**EDIT :** It was a silly mistake, adding at the beginning of `sys.paths` works. I had some other `import` statement elsewhere that was executed first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is bad bad idea to do something like `force importing the local package`.
2. Python3 **always** import the built-in modules first, and obviously you're using Python3 cause Python2 is local-first.
3. I don't know how to solve this problem, if I were you I'd rename that file.

**edit**

You don't use `append` cause append is to the end. Use `insert`.
Tested on my cpu. I created a `requests.py` in another folder.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0 ,"path-to-another-folder/")
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
>>>
```

If I don't do `sys.path.insert(0 ,"path-to-another-folder/")`, `requests` is imported normally.

Comment: No actually I'm using Python 2 and 3 (the package should be compatible with both in the end). However, I get the same behaviour for Python 2 also. It's not a built-in that I'm trying to overwrite (that would be a bad idea indeed), just my own package that I installed via `setup.py`. Renaming is quite unpractical because I'd have to rename - install - rename every time I try to update the installed version.

Comment: @greschd That's interestring, cause in Python2 you should have no problem `import your_script` if that script exists in the same folder.

Comment: It's not in the same folder, I add it via `sys.path.append()`

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was just a silly mistake, I had an import in another file (I did try `insert`, but not everywhere).